# Background video with Html5 and CSS not fixed attachment

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
video {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
}
```

I try this one it's working fine but it's fixed in the whole body...

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are trying to accomplish? position:fixed on element will show the element on the screen even if you scroll.

Comment: What is not working? `position: fixed` positions the element based on the viewport. Maybe you are looking for `position: absolute` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should set your selector for example:

```
#headerid video {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
}
```

It will fix the video in the headerid element. It could be div but you must fix the width and height of the div.